# How to display a message to the user about maintenance and nightly jobs in PHP + MS SQL application

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, smarty, sweetalert

we have nightly jobs updating the database(SQL server) and tables.And we have a PHP application which displays the data(And does CRUD). These jobs take few hours to run, When these jobs are running, We would like to inform user that "Job/data update is in progress, Please come back later".
  Also we do have a table which has start time of the first job and end time of the last job.

**Question**

What(and how) is the best way to check the table for the job start and then display the "Maintenance" message?

Comment: Same start and end time each day?

Comment: This is really primarily an opinion based question so it will probably be closed. You could use configuration or you could have cron update web server or proxy configuration. It's hard to say what the best way is as it depends on your application demands.

Comment: He doesn't ask for the best way to do it, which would be opinion based. He askes for **one** way to do it.

Comment: Add a field to your table for the "status" of the job. Update your "status" field at the beginning and end of the package. Report "status" to user.

Comment: as comments say, you have many ways to achieve that. beside cron / update status already mentionned, you can add a time checking in the page accessing the data: if time is in your set time gap -> display a message (ie: sorry, closed until xxAM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a table to your database, Add a row in that table in the start of the each job (probably the very first step in the job to insert this row).
2. At the end of the job delete that row for that job (the very last step in the job to delete that row).
3. In application code check for any rows in that table, if the row exists show your message ("Come back later bla bla")
4. If there is no row in that table application works as usual.

Table schema should be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ProcessMonitor 
(
  JobName NVARCHAR(1000)
, StatusID  INT
)
GO
```

*Note*

You can add additional steps in the job to change the statusID of the job, and only block users when they absolutely need to be, else allow them in with few warnings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, to check which jobs are currently running in the server..

```
SELECT
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS current_executed_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
    ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

Courtesy: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58859/script-to-see-running-jobs-in-sql-server-with-job-start-time